# What to do when a node.js API function has no async version?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, buffer, event-loop

I am trying to create a secure random token

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { promisify } = require("util");
exports.createRandomToken = async () => {
  const randomBytes = promisify(crypto.randomBytes);

  const secretToken = await randomBytes(
    parseInt(process.env.RANDOMBYTES_BYTES_NUMBER)
  );

  const secretTokenHex = secretToken.toString("hex"); //sync
  return secretTokenHex;
};
```

Although [crypto.randomBytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) has an async version,
[buffer.toString()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)  has not.

What could I do in this situation in order not to block the event loop (a must follow practice as [express.js documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#dont-use-synchronous-functions) says?

Comment: Not *everything* must be (or can be) async; parseInt and promisify also aren't, in your example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, I see, but then the web server would have a very bad performance when it is running sync code

Comment: Not necessarily. If *long-running* processes are blocking then that can be a problem, but you'll always have *some* blocking, because otherwise your program doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, so in cases like running the toString() method is not a problem, but if I would process a file of 10GB synchronously that would be a problem, right?